# Как централизовать текст внури поля v-text-field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Стандартные средства css использовать не получается

Comment: добавте пример кода

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.center input {
   text-align: center
}
```

VUE

```
<v-text-field class="center">
</v-text-field>
```